# How to use LAG & LEAD window functions for different groups of observations

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, databricks

this is a question about using LAG and LEAD window functions on Databricks using Spark SQL but I think the problem is not necessarily related to a specific SQL dialect.

I have an input table that lists visits for different customers (ID) and a flag that indicates "special visits":

```
ID | date       | special_visit
-------------------------------
A  | 2018-01-01 | 0            
A  | 2018-02-01 | 1            
A  | 2018-03-01 | 1            
B  | 2018-01-02 | 0            
B  | 2018-02-02 | 0            
B  | 2018-03-02 | 1
```

What I'd like to create is the following table:

```
ID | date       | special_visit | prev_visit | next_visit | prev_special_visit | next_special_visit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A  | 2018-01-01 | 0             | NULL       | 2018-02-01 | NULL               | 2018-02-01
A  | 2018-02-01 | 1             | 2018-01-01 | 2018-03-01 | NULL               | 2018-03-01  
A  | 2018-03-01 | 1             | 2018-02-01 | NULL       | 2018-02-01         | NULL
B  | 2018-01-02 | 0             | NULL       | 2018-02-02 | NULL               | 2018-03-02
B  | 2018-02-02 | 0             | 2018-01-02 | 2018-03-02 | NULL               | 2018-03-02
B  | 2018-03-02 | 1             | 2018-02-02 | NULL       | NULL               | NULL
```

For each visit it shows me the next/previous visit (every special visit also counts as a "normal" visit) and the next/previous special visit for every ID.

What I get so far is the following output:

```
ID | date       | special_visit | prev_visit | next_visit | prev_special_visit | next_special_visit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A  | 2018-01-01 | 0             | NULL       | 2018-02-01 | NULL               | NULL
A  | 2018-02-01 | 1             | 2018-01-01 | 2018-03-01 | NULL               | 2018-03-01  
A  | 2018-03-01 | 1             | 2018-02-01 | NULL       | 2018-02-01         | NULL
B  | 2018-01-02 | 0             | NULL       | 2018-02-02 | NULL               | NULL
B  | 2018-02-02 | 0             | 2018-01-02 | 2018-03-02 | NULL               | NULL
B  | 2018-03-02 | 1             | 2018-02-02 | NULL       | NULL               | NULL
```

with this query:

```
WITH special_visits AS (
SELECT  ID
       ,date
       ,LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) AS prev_special_visit
       ,LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) AS next_special_visit
FROM input
WHERE special_visit = 1)

SELECT ID
      ,special_visit
      ,LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) AS prev_visit
      ,LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) AS next_visit
      ,special_visits.prev_special_visit
      ,special_visits.next_special_visit
FROM input
LEFT JOIN special_visits USING(ID, date)
```

The problem here is, that I can only observe the previous/next special visit if the observation (row) is a special visit itself. I was hoping that some kind of filter within the window function like this might work:

```
LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date WHERE special_visit = 1) AS prev_special_visit
```

But unfortunately it is not working. Do you have an idea how to create the desired output?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `LEAD()` and `LAG()` are optimal for this.  Instead:

```
SELECT ID, date,
       LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) AS prev_visit,
       LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) AS next_visit,
       MAX(CASE WHEN special_visit = 1 THEN date END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as prev_special_visit,
       MIN(CASE WHEN special_visit = 1 THEN date END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as next_special_visit
FROM input
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,
I tested your query on SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/404d1/3
(I hope this link is working and you can see the results.)
But unfortunately it doesn't produce the desired result.

Comment: Okay, you just have to remove the order specification "DESC" and then it's working fine. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dates are always increasing, you could do conditional `min()`s and `max()`s, with row frames, as follows:

```
select 
    t.*,
    lag(date) over(partition by id order by date) pre_visit,
    lead(date) over(partition by id order by date) next_visit,
    max(case when special_visit = 1 then date end) over(
        partition by id 
        order by date
        row between unbounded preceding and 1 preceeding
    ) prev_special_visit,
    min(case when special_visit = 1 then date end) over(
        partition by id 
        order by date
        row between 1 following and unbounded following
    ) next_special_visit
from input t
```

Comment: This query is working fine. I just had to remove some typos:
- "row" to "rows"
- "preceeding" to "preceding"
Thank you!